# C# contravariance with method arguments

Tags: c#, action, contravariance

I'm trying to solve some simple study task, which includes writing an interpreter of some simple language with 4 methods - Set, Sum, Print, Remove; first 2 methods have 2 arguments - variable name and int value to set to variable or sum to its current value, and last 2 methods have only one argument - variable name

The method that I'm writing takes string , for example "set a 3" or "print a", and should work as interpreter of this string (do appropriate actions).
The obvious way is to use `switch` construction (switch by first word), but I've read that it's always better to use `Dictionary` instead of `switch`, so I've defined

```
Dictionary<string, Action<ActionArg>> methods
```

, where `ActionArg` is defined supertype with 2 inherited types:

```
abstract class ActionArg {} 
class ActionArgVal : ActionArg { public string Val {get; set; } }
class ActionArgValVar : ActionArgVal { public int Var {get; set; } }
```

, and have defined 4 methods, for example,

```
void Set(ActionArgValVar) { ... }
```

But when I'm trying to write `methods = new Dictionary<string, Action<ActionArg>> { {"set", Set}, ... }`, there occurs an error, because `Action<ActionArgValVar>` couldn't be assigned to `Action<ActionArg>` because of contravariance of `Action`.

Is there any way to solve this using `Dictionary` or tasks like this are better to be solved by simple `switch` construction?

Comment: "*but I've read that it's always better to use Dictionary instead of switch*" -- I think that's going a bit far

Comment: Have you thought about making _Set, Sum, Print, Remove_ methods generic itself and use the generic constraint to limit a types for your interpreter? Please, share the examples of these methods as well?

Comment: `private static void Set<T>(T arg) where T : ActionArg`  Pavel Anikhouski that works, thanks for advice! (now Dictionary assigns correctly) canton7 sorry, my English is not very good, you mean it's too complexity to this simple task?

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski But I have one more question now, in every method now I should use cast, such as, `var argValVar = (ActionArgVarVal)arg`, or there is more elegant way?

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski  `void Set<T>(T arg) where T : ActionArg { var argValVar = (ActionArgVarVal)arg; //working with argValVar }` `methods = new Dictionary<string, Action<ActionArg>>
            {
                { "set", Set } 
            };` or you meant something else, sorry?   canton7 seems understood - too common phrase about Dictionary and switch

Comment: (`arg as ActionArgVarVal`, to be correct)

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski about examples - for example, "set a 5" defines var a with value 5, "sum a 4" makes a 9, "print a" displays it, "remove a" removes it from memory so "print a" after it would produce exception. I didn't write this examples because my question doesn't depend on semantic of these methods..